# Prevent dynamic content loss on toggle

Tags: mootools

I am retrieving some data from the server and update the html contents of a div like this:

```
var req = new Request.JSON({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'index.php',
    data: {},
    onSuccess: function(r) {
        $('my_div').set('html',r.output);
        }
    }
});
```

I wish to be able to 'toggle' the results as well and I use this:

```
var mySlide = new Fx.Slide('my_div');
$('toggle_link').addEvent('click', function(event){
    event.stop();
    mySlide.toggle();
    event.stop();
});
```

This works only once presumably due to the fact that html contents are retrieved dynamically. Is there a way to prevent loosing the html contents from my Div and show the toggle effect?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a syntax error: a double `}` closing `onSuccess` function. Apart from that, your code looks ok, and in fact it works: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ytbu/1/

Comment: Thanks. It seems though that I had to update the height of the div to make some space for the results after the first toggle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem about height, you need to set the `resetHeight: true` option to your `Fx.Slide`. Updated example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ytbu/5/)**.

Comment: Unfortunately the resetHeight didn't change much. I guess the space is not allocated onLoad but after the content is generated. A workaround is to play with the style.display property but the visual effect is not the same..

Comment: I don't know anything of your HTML/CSS, so I cannot help you further :)

Comment: Thanks lorenzo you already helped a lot! Maybe the resetHeight is not working on mootools 1.2..